# How do I reset my Open File dialog box on Mac?

Tags: macos, file-management

Every time I open a file in any application, the open dialog box looks like this.  The divider in the center is pulled all the way to the right.  How can I reset this so that it is centered by default?  Thanks.

[image: My Open File Dialog box with the center bar pulled all the way to the right]

Comment: Stupid question: can you drag it back and does it just default to the far right again?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue.  It turns out there was a certain file in the "Favorites" list that was excessively long.  This was pushing the sidebar automatic resize to the far right.  To remove items from sidebar Favorites, hold Command and drag file to the Trash.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all saved application states under

```
/Users/<user name>/Library/Saved Application State/*
```

Also remove saved application preference files

```
/Users/<user name>/Library/Preferences/*
```

If you have a plist editor you could try editing the entries for NSNavPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run this in the terminal

```
defaults delete com.google.Chrome NSNavPanelExpandedSizeForOpenMode
```